# Evaluation of the given integral for the given surface

Tags: multiple-integral

I need to calculate the integral:

$$\iiint_E \sqrt{x^2+z^2}\,dV$$

such that $E$ is the solid bounded by $y=x^2+z^2$ and $y=4$.

I am not able to decide the limits of integration, a walk through for this would be really appreciated. Additionally, is there a way I can solve this using cylindrical co-ordinates?

Comment: Can you sketch the region $E$ (which is a solid region, not a surface, btw)?

Comment: And yes, you can solve this using cylindrical coordinates, but using a relabeling of the usual coordinates. In particular, the occurrence of $x^2 + z^2$ in both the integrand and the equation for one of the bounding surfaces suggests using cylindrical coordinates $(r, \theta, y)$, where $r^2 = x^2 + z^2$.

Comment: Thanks for the edit on the solid. Didn't realize that. And I don't exactly know how to sketch the region on my computer. What I know for sure is that the solid is a truncated paraboloid which runs from $y=0$ to $y=4$.

Comment: As for sketching, first draw the intersection of the solid with, e.g., the $xy$-plane. This means we set $z = 0$ in both of the equations defining the surface---giving $y = x^2$ and $y = 4$---and then sketch the region bounded by those curves. Then, we can observe that the cylindrical expression for the region doesn't involve $\theta$, so it must be rotationally symmetric about the $y$-axis---this gives exactly a truncated paraboloid like you say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Let use cylindrical coordinates with

- $x=r\cos \theta$
- $z=r\sin \theta$
- $y=y$
- $dV=r \,dy\, dr\, d\theta$

then

$$\iiint_E \sqrt{(x^2+z^2)}.dV=\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\theta\int_0^4 dy\int_0^{\sqrt y}r^2 \, dr$$

In cartesian coordinates we have

$$\iiint_E \sqrt{(x^2+z^2)}.dV=\int_{0}^{4}dy\int_{-\sqrt y}^{\sqrt y} dx\int_{-\sqrt{y-x^2} }^{\sqrt{y-x^2}}\sqrt{x^2+z^2}\, dz$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helped. But can you tell me how can I evaluate this integral if I am constrained to use Cartesian coordinates? How will I evaluate limits for the integral?

Comment: @AanchitNayak I've added the set up for cartesian coordinates.

Comment: To find the set up you need to understand the region bounds. In this case, fixed $y$, in the planes x-z we have circles $x^2+z^2=y$ centered at the origin with radius $\sqrt y$ while in y-z and y-x planes we have parabolas $y=x^2$ and $y=z^2$.